# Creation of Dockerfile for Android GitLab CI

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm creating my own Dockerfile for Runner, which is about to work in Gitlab CI as Android project runner. The problem is, that I'm about to connect the physical device to a machine, on which I'm about to deploy that runner. As usually with Linux machine, I was trying to add 51-android.rules into /etc/dev/rules.d as in this tutorial: [Udev Setup](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules)
During `docker build .` command execution, I got error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: udevadm: not found
```

My questions are:

1. 1) Is it possible, to connect the physical Android device to docker-running OS?
2. 2) If 1) yes, where is my mistake?

The problematic dockerfile part:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
#Ubuntu setup
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget

...

#Setup Android Udev Rules
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules/master/51-android.rules 
RUN mv -y `pwd`/51-android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
RUN chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
RUN udevadm control --reload-rules
RUN service udev restart
RUN usermod -a -G plugdev `whoami`
RUN adb kill-server
RUN adb devices 

#Cleaning 
RUN apt-get clean
```

Comment: This post, written by an Android developer of Snapchat, might help you: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/. He explains how to build and test an Android app with GitLab CI, gives the code you need for .gitlab-ci.yml and break it into parts, explained one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The philosophy of Docker is to have one process running per container. There usually is no Init System so you cannot use services as you are used to.

I don't know if it's possible to achieve what you are trying to do but I think that you want the udev-rules on the host and add the device when you are starting it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container-device

Also you may want to read https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/apt-get
Every `RUN` creates a new layer, only **adding** information to the container.

Having said that, you probably want to have `adb devices` as the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` of your container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it it great, I made Android Device visible from the inside of Docker's build. Now I faced another problem:
While Gitlab-CI starts my Runner -> It goes to docker and creates new build from my Image. Unfortunately, every new build needs a confirmation of ADB Debugging on a device's screen. Is there any way to work it around?